# getting 'int' object is not iterable error

Tags: python, keyboard, pyautogui

i made a code and wanted that it types numbers from 12300 to 13000 but i got this error

```
 File "C:\Users\akki kisu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 844, in write
    for letter in text:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

this is my main code

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
numb = 12300
while True:
   numb=numb+1
# # (x=937, y=406number
# # x=1267, y=419get record
# 1415,414 reset
   pyautogui.click(937,406)
   keyboard.write(numb)
   time.sleep(2)
   pyautogui.click(1267,419)
   time.sleep(5)
   keyboard.press_and_release('windows+shift+s')
   time.sleep(2)
   pyautogui.click(1030, 52)
   time.sleep(1)
   pyautogui.click(1361,1049)#word
   keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+v')
   time.sleep(1)
   pyautogui.click(867,1057)
   time.sleep(1)
   pyautogui.click(1415,414)
```

please suggest a way to resolve it

Comment: `numb` should be converted to a `str`ing -> `keybord.write(str(numb))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 12, instead of writing `keyboard.write(numb)`, write `keyboard.write(str(numb))`. This changes numb which is an `int` type to a `str` type before writing it.

Comment: can you explain why we should use str instead of int

Comment: @RathoreBrothers when you use int instead of str, it raises an error in the __init__.py file of the keyboard module.